# How can I use my Android device like removable device on Debian?

Tags: linux, usb, debian, android, sd-card

```
uname -a
```

> Linux mdo 4.9.0-8-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 4.9.144-3.1 (2019-02-19) i686 GNU/Linux

I'd like to use my Android device like removable device via USB, ofc. (I have sd-card inside Android). How can I mount its (sd-cards) for using? Which packets i need to install for solve this?

Also, no one USB-mode can't helps me:

[image]

Description:

- Сharging only
- Transfer for files
- Transfer for files (PTP)

Comment: Android uses MTP/PTP since a long time ago and it has many advantages over the old ways, the one you want but shouldn't and can't because not available. You may need to install something in Debian to enable support but probably not if it's a current release. Then choose "Transfer for files" which is MPT for accessing anything but the camera folder or PTP exclusively for the camera folder.

Comment: Nothing not helps. I tried do it! Probably, i need install something

Comment: Older Ubuntu releases needed something bloke mtptools or something like that. Googling what you need for Debian should be easy enough though.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia, ok, 10q for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's Android 3.0 or newer, then **you can't**.

Android doesn't expose direct access to mass storage because it's too low-level. It doesn't want you to change partition geometry, format them and be able to access every single bit. It also does want to be able to access SD card all the time and to expose it as a mass storage device, it would have to give the PC exclusive access. Older Androids did this, newer don't. Instead, they provide filesystem access through the MTP protocol.

Since Android 6.0 it's even more complicated: you can format the SD card as *adopted storage*. It becomes encrypted with a random key stored in the main memory and is seamlessly integrated with internal storage. This enables Android to securely install apps to SD cards. Such SD card can be accessed only through MTP in this specific phone where it was adopted. Other phones and PCs can't read such card because it's encrypted.